# How can I assign integer values to 4 bit binary in python starting from 64 to 512? Say 0001 = 64, 0010 = 96, .... 1111 = 512

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to assign the values 64 to 512, with intervals of 32 in a 4 bit binary string. So, instead of the usual values of 0001 = 1, 0010=2 .... 1111 = 15; the values should be as follows,

0001 = 64
0010 = 96
.
.
.
1110 = 480
1111 = 512

## tried to use a dictionary to do that, but don't know how to use it in BitArray

filter_number1 = {0b0001: 64,
                  0b0010: 96,
                  0b0011: 128,
                  0b0100: 160,
                  0b0101: 192,
                  0b0110: 224,
                  0b0111: 256,
                  0b1000: 288,
                  0b1001: 320,
                  0b1010: 352,
                  0b1011: 384,
                  0b1100: 416,
                  0b1101: 448,
                  0b1110: 480,
                  0b1111: 512}

Comment: Why do you need this translation to begin with? What is the original and actual problem you need to solve? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us, and describe your problem with it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the not so good way of asking the question. The problem is to use the 4 bit binary in a BitArray that I can use for genetic algorithm. Usually, when we use BitArray(variable_name[0:4] for example, the algorithm will mutate on 4 bits but the value is from 0 to 15 only. I want to assign each bit from 64 to 512 instead of 0 to 15.